# how to use BufferedReader class to take character and string input from user?

Tags: java

I write a code using BufferedReader class to take input from the user.  first I took character input and String then tried to print both the inputs on the output screen and some weird output I got.

```
import java.io.*;
public class scratch_1{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        InputStreamReader InputObj = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader BufferObj = new BufferedReader(InputObj);

        System.out.println("enter the Character: ");
        char c = (char)BufferObj.read();

        System.out.println("enter the string: ");
        String str = BufferObj.readLine();



        System.out.println("entered string: "+str);
        System.out.println("entered Character: "+c);
    }


}
```

Comment: please run the above code in your system

Comment: can you share the output you got?

Comment: Please ***show*** your input as well as your observed and expected output. You know that the Java console cannot read individual chars, one at a time, that it must read the complete line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By strange output do you mean this?

```
enter the Character: 
a
enter the string: 
entered string: 
entered Character: a
```

It's not a strange output, because `BufferedReader#read` reads exactly **one** character and `BufferedReader.readLine` reads everything from the beginning of the line to newline character (`\n`).

When you press Enter, you're pushing `\n` to STDIN. So, in this example, my input was `a\n`. First `read` recognized letter 'a' and then `readLine` read '\n' symbol, thus saving empty string to `str`.

#### Fix

To fix this, you need to omit the newline character by calling `read` again.

```
InputStreamReader InputObj = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
BufferedReader BufferObj = new BufferedReader(InputObj);

System.out.println("enter the Character: ");
char c = (char)BufferObj.read();
BufferObj.read(); // omit '\n' going after previous char

System.out.println("enter the string: ");
String str = BufferObj.readLine();

System.out.println("entered string: "+str);
System.out.println("entered Character: "+c);
```

Running this code gives the next output

```
enter the Character: 
a
enter the string: 
string
entered string: string
entered Character: a
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean why it just skips the next readline after entering the character, if that's the case you just need to put BufferObj.read(); after each read() function, so your code will look like this:

```
    ...
    System.out.println("enter the Character: ");
    char c = (char) BufferObj.read();

    BufferObj.read();

    System.out.println("enter the string: ");
    String str = BufferObj.readLine();

    System.out.println("entered string: " + str);
    System.out.println("entered Character: " + c);
    ...
```